# signal handler ending the process after its execution

Tags: c, signal-handling

I'm coding a program and I settled up a signal handler for `SIGINT`:

```
volatile int exit_program = 0; //Global variable

void exit_client() {
    write(1, "Disconnecting...\n", strlen("Disconnecting...\n"));
    exit_program = 1;
}
```

Then in main I told the process to react with `exit_client()` when a `SIGINT` is received.

```
int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, exit_client);
    //...
}
```

Later on in the main process I have the following code:

```
while (!exit_program) {

    //...

    socket_rcv(server_socket);
}

close(server_socket);
write(1, "Disconnected\n", strlen("Disconnected\n"));
```

I use `socket_rcv()` to receive data from the server socket and also to send a `SIGINT` to the process if the `read()` return value is 0 (when the server disconnects). I do this executing: `raise(SIGINT)`:

```
socket_data socket_rcv(int socket) {
        
    //...

    do {
        bytes_read = read(socket, sequence + (115 - total_bytes), total_bytes+10);

        if (bytes_read == -1) write(1, "Read error\n", strlen("Read error\n"));
        if (bytes_read == 0) raise(SIGINT);
        total_bytes -= bytes_read;

    } while (total_bytes > 0);

    //...
}
```

But, when executing both server and client and disconnecting the server first, to see how the client reacts (should print `Disconnecting...` and then `Disconnected` as well as the server socket is closed), I only get the print in the signal handler to confirm the signal handler executes but then the program terminates and it doesn't continue it's execution in order to close the socket and execute the last `write(1, "Disconnected\n", strlen("Disconnected\n"));`.

Why does it terminate and how can I fix this?

Also, might be irrelevant but `socket_rcv()` function is declared in another `.c` file, including its `.h` module where the main process is.

Comment: Why do you need the signal at all? Why not just set `exit_program` directly?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Note that in general it is better to use `sigaction` instead of `signal`.

Comment: @kaylum because the program does not end until I press `CTRL + C` which sends a `SIGINT` to that process to then exit the loop and `free()` used memory and close some file descriptors

Comment: Not sure how pressing Ctrl+C fits into the picture, you might want to integrate that into the overall story. Be aware that `signal()` is installing a one-shot handler, if you get two sigints, the second one will use the default handler and immediately nuke the process. `raise` will not exit the socket_rcv function so you will probably get the disconnecting print, go back to being stuck inside `socket_rcv` and then press ^C and see above.

Comment: I second what @kaylum is saying. You do not need signals to send this kind of message to yourself. Set the variable and return from `socket_rcv`, that's it. You don't have to clown around with signals and `raise`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters, why use a signal handler when you can set `exit_program` directly?

Anyway, your problem seems to be lying somewhere else (maybe `read`?) or you're not giving us the full picture because this piece of code works:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile int exit_program = 0;

void exit_handler(int sig) {
    write(1, "exit_handler\n", strlen("exit_handler\n"));
    exit_program = 1;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;

    signal(SIGINT, exit_handler);

    while (!exit_program) {
        write(1, "loop\n", strlen("loop\n"));

        if (i == 1) {
            raise(SIGINT);
        }

        ++i;
    }

    write(1, "done\n", strlen("done\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
loop
loop
exit_handler
done
```